# Python GUI EntryButtons

Tags: python

I'm making a small GUI application that deals with grades and whatnot and outputs the highest grades and etc.

Here's a part of the code:

```
root = Tk()

gradeList = []

def addGradeObject(name, percentage):
    gradeList.append(Grade(name, percentage))
    updateOutput()
    print(gradeList)

def undoAdd():
    try:
        gradeList.pop(len(gradeList) - 1)
        updateOutput()
        print(gradeList)
    except Exception:
        pass

def updateOutput():
    highestGrade.setText(highest_grade(gradeList))
    lowestGrade.setText(lowest_grade(gradeList))
    numFailed.setText(num_failed(gradeList))

addButton = Button(text = "Add Grade", command = lambda: addGradeObject    (entryA.get(), entryB.get())).grid(row = 1, column = 4)
undoButton = Button(text = "Undo", command = undoAdd).grid(row = 2, column = 4)

entryA = Entry()
entryA.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
entryB = Entry()
entryB.grid(row = 1, column = 2)

highestGrade = Entry()
highestGrade.grid(row = 2, column = 1)
lowestGrade = Entry()
lowestGrade.grid(row = 3, column = 1)
numFailed = Entry()
numFailed.grid(row = 4, column = 1)

root.title("Grade Checker")


root.mainloop()
```

The problem is I'm getting this error:

```
AttributeError: 'Entry' object has no attribute 'setText'
```

I don't understand. When you create an Entry box, doesn't the object of class "Entry" have an attribute/method that allows you to set text to it? I really don't know why it's not working

Comment: No, `Entry` does not have a method `setText`. That name does not even respect Python conventions (it would be `set_text`, but that does not exist either). Use `configure` instead. Best thing would be to use a `StringVar`

Answer (score 2):

`Entry` methods can be found [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm#reference).  As far as I can tell, there is no `setText` method.  There is however an `insert` method that you could use to set the text (though you might wand to `delete` the current text first).

```
def set_text(entry, text):
    entry.delete(0, tkinter.END)
    entry.insert(0 text)
```

Alternatively, you can hook the entry up to a `StringVar` and use it's `.set()` and `.get()` methods.  e.g. (from the linked docs above):

```
v = StringVar()
e = Entry(master, textvariable=v)
e.pack()

v.set("a default value")
s = v.get()
```